# Pegar dados de array e dar update em tabela

Tags: php

Bom dia.

Estou fazendo um `INSERT` no banco via `PHP`, com dados vindo de um `SELECT MULTIPLE`. Os dados deste `SELECT` vem de uma tabela do banco:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="numerosdasorte[]" class="form-control" multiple="">

   <?php
      $consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM cota1 ORDER BY cota ASC");
      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   ?>

   <option value="<?php echo $linha['cota']; ?>"><?php echo $linha['cota']; ?></option>

   <?php } ?>

</select>
```

Quando realizo o `SUBMIT` do `FORM`, pego a variável e coloco as vírgulas para separar os números escolhidos:

**PHP:**

```
$numerosdasorte = '';
    foreach($_POST['numerosdasorte'] as $numeros){
        $numerosdasorte .= ',' . $numeros;
    }

  $numerosdasorte = ltrim($numerosdasorte, ',');
```

O código funciona normalmente, salva no banco exatamente do jeito que quero. A questão é a seguinte: Preciso separar esses números para fazer o `UPDATE` na tabela `cota1`, para que, ao entrar novamente, eles estejam indisponíveis. Na tabela, setei como `BOOLEAN`, então preciso fazer este `UPDATE` para indisponibilizar o número para o próximo cadastro.

Enfim, não consigo pensar numa forma de fazer isso. Um amigo sugeriu fazer um `UPDATE` antes de `FORM` ser submetido, na escolha do número. Mas, se a pessoa desistir do cadastro, o número vai ficar indisponível, mesmo se o `FORM` não for submetido.

Penso que, se conseguir separar esses números, posso fazer o `UPDATE` de cada um deles na tabela. O que acham?

Comment: Gostaria da justificativa do "downvote", para saber onde estou errando. Para mim, é uma dúvida. Acho que todo downvote deveria ter justificativa obrigatória.

Comment: vc quer separar esses numeros em um array? sendo cada numero em 1 posição?

Comment: Arthur, obrigado pelo seu tempo. Penso que assim seria mais fácil de atualizar a tabela de números no banco. A não ser que tenha outra forma, gostaria de sua opinião, por gentileza,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supondo que sua variavel chega assim

Ex:

**Atribuição**:

```
$var = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
```

**Dump**:

```
string(17) "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

você pode dar um *explode*.

**Exemplo**:

```
$exploded = explode(",",$var);
```

o **output** de *$exploded* seria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
)
```

Documentação da funcão *explode* pode ser encontrada [aqui!](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: Bacana, obrigado! Vou tentar aqui em alguns minutos, e já retorno!

Comment: Quando dou o `ECHO` no `$value`, só vem o último número escolhido.

Comment: editei a resposta, acho que isto te servirá melhor amigo

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou certinho, obrigado! Agora só preciso pensar em como não fazer em todos os números, o código ficaria enorme. Grande abraço, tópico fechado!